# Read tab delimited text file into MySQL table with PHP

Tags: php, mysql, import

I am trying to read in a series of tab delimited text files into existing MySQL tables. The code I have is quite simple:

```
$lines = file("import/file_to_import.txt");

foreach ($lines as $line_num => $line) {
    if($line_num > 1) {
        $arr = explode("\t", $line);
        $sql = sprintf("INSERT INTO my_table VALUES('%s', '%s', '%s', %s, %s);", trim((string)$arr[0]), trim((string)$arr[1]), trim((string)$arr[2]), trim((string)$arr[3]), trim((string)$arr[4]));
        mysql_query($sql, $database) or die(mysql_error());
    }
}
```

But no matter what I do (hence the casting before each variable in the sprintf statement) I get the "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 1" error.

I echo out the code, paste it into a MySQL editor and it runs fine, it just won't execute from the PHP script.

What am I doing wrong??

Si

UPDATE: Here are the echoe'd SQL's:

```
INSERT INTO wheelbase (WheelBaseCode, LanguageCode, WheelBaseDescription) VALUES ('A1', 'GBEN', '2.50-2.99m')
INSERT INTO wheelbase (WheelBaseCode, LanguageCode, WheelBaseDescription) VALUES ('A2', 'GBEN', '3.00-3.49m')
INSERT INTO wheelbase (WheelBaseCode, LanguageCode, WheelBaseDescription) VALUES ('A3', 'GBEN', '3.50-3.99m')
INSERT INTO wheelbase (WheelBaseCode, LanguageCode, WheelBaseDescription) VALUES ('A4', 'GBEN', '4.00-4.49m')
```

Interestingly, I now have it creating the correct number of rows in the table, but the values it inserts are empty...

Could this be an encoding issue in the source text file??

Answer (score 2):

You don't need the string cast, the data will already be strings.

Make sure there are no quotes in the file data. Echo out the sql string before you run it to see if there's something obviously wrong.

Change the SQL to:

```
"INSERT INTO my_table (`field1Name`, `field2Name`, `field3Name`, `field4Name`, `field5Name`) VALUES('%s', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s');"
```

This change includes the field names, and quoting the last two values.

Comment: I know I didnt need the string cast, this was in there just to make sure I wasn't going mad. Your code should work as well as mine, but it doesn't. I dont need to specify field names as I am inserting into all five fields (so I can just do INSERT INTO my_table VALUES). Also, the last two are type DOUBLE, not VARCHAR. There are no quotes in the data, and even if I only process the first couple of rows, I still get the error.

Comment: Well, echo out the queries before you run them. Add them to your question.

Comment: If you run those queries, and get rows added to the table, but those fields are blank... I'm stumped. You may want to post the table structure, but I can't think of anything that would leave the fields blank.

Answer (score 0):

I dont like you method in general. Maybe you fix your "first" problem with the missing 
rows. Whats about some special character like '" backslash or SQL injection?
I think you should use prepared statements which PDO provides and call the "bindValue" of
the statement. It is a stable and buildin PHP lib. Or you can use dbTube.org instead
which is a graphical import tool.

Greeting

Shutter

Answer (score 0):

From [PHP.net](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fputcsv.php):

```
<?php
    fputcsv($fp, $foo, "\t");
?>
```

you just forgot that single quotes are literal...meaning whatever you put there that's what will come out so `\t` would be same as `t` because `\` in that case would be only used for escaping but if you use double quotes then that would work.

Comment: Wait, single quotes inside double quotes?