# How To Iterate UTF-8 String To Mysql

Tags: php, mysql

Could please somebody help me find out how to iterate these raw txt data to mysql. The format is

user id | item id | rating | timestamp

and i want to insert these data to my table in MySql (using PHPmyAdmin), let's say the table structure is : user_id (int), item_id(int), rating(int), timestamp(int) with its name "Rating".

So, i want to know how to insert these data to my table, i'm fine with php, or if there are easier way to do this.

[image: txt data]

Comment: these look like if they are tab separated. Consider http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2745637/read-tab-delimited-text-file-into-mysql-table-with-php or similar existing questions or just `LOAD DATA INFILE`

Comment: With this data the file got to have a UTF-8 BOM to be definitely UTF-8. But it should be very easy to import this with phpMyAdmin.

Comment: @VMai i've tried the dumb way with direct importing the UTF-8 file.. But it doesnt work.
Maybe using explode is the easiest way, i'm gonna try it, thank you Gordon

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to generate raw SQL queries, you can do so by using find and replace in your text editor (that looks like Notepad++). I'm guessing that your delimiters are tabs.

1. Find and replace all tab characters and replace them with a comma. We do not need to quote anything as all of your fields are integers.
2. Find and replace all newline characters and replace them with a SQL query.

Execute these commands in regular expression mode:

### Columns

Find: `\t`

Replace: `,`

### Rows

Find: `\r\n` (if that doesn't find anything, look for `\n`)

Replace: `);\r\nINSERT INTO Rating (user_id, item_id, rating, timestamp) VALUES (`

On the first row, insert the text `INSERT INTO Rating (user_id, item_id, rating, timestamp) VALUES (` to make the row a valid SQL statement.

On the last row, remove any trailing portions of SQL query after the last semicolon.

Copy and paste this into your PHPMyAdmin and it should be all good.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way I have found for doing similar is to use Excel. Import the text file into a new document - judging by the look it should be easy to seperate the columns as they appear to be tab delimited. Once you have the required columns set up a string concatenation to include the values... kind of like

=CONCATENATE("INSERT INTO `Rating` SET `user_id`='",A1,"', `item_id`='",B1,"', `rating`='",C1,"', `timestamp`='",D1,"';")

Then repeat for all rows, copy and paste into sql client

Comment: traditional way, i like it. :D

Answer (score 1):

you can use [toad for mysql](http://www.quest.com/toad-for-mysql/) , import wisard and you create a table with the same structure (user id | item id | rating | timestamp) of you file after import all data you export the sql insert of you new table.

Comment: thank you bro, from now on i'm using toad for optimizing mysql.
Cause phpmyadmin can't handle 10M records.. haha